# draw in canvas placing and image in the background for reference

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas

I have defined a function to draw a canvas and then pass it as an image for reference of a new canvas to draw over it.
What I see is that since is an image in the same position of the canvas i can not draw over it.
How could i make it so i use the saved image as a reference in the background of the canvas to draw over?

```
function Canvas() {
  const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState('');
  const [savedImageData, setSavedImageData] = useState(null);
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(400);



  const saveCanvas = (e) => {
    if (canvasRef.current) {
      const canvas = canvasRef.current;
      const dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(); // Save canvas as data URL
      setSavedImageData(dataURL);
      console.log(setSavedImageData)
    }
  };

  const handleLoadData = () => {
    if (savedImageData) {
      console.log(savedImageData)
      setImageUrl(savedImageData);

    }
    const newcanva  = canvasRef.current
    
  };

 return (
    <div>
      <h2>Canvas Component</h2>
      <div style={{ position: 'relative', width: '400px', height: '400px' }}>
        <canvas
          ref={canvasRef}
          width={width}
          height={400}
          style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            backgroundColor: 'lightgray',
          }}
          onMouseDown={startDrawing}
          onMouseMove={draw}
          onMouseUp={stopDrawing}
          onMouseOut={stopDrawing}
        />
     <img src={imageUrl} alt='baby'></img>
      </div>
      <button onClick={saveCanvas}>Save Drawing</button>
      <button onClick={handleLoadData}>Show Saved Image</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```